# Unable to execute jdbc query on a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, oracle10g

I am trying to create an html page which takes some input and saves that data in oracle database using jdbc and servlet.
This is the HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="HelloServlet" method="post">
 <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="id">
 <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name">
 <input type="text" placeholder="SALARY" name="salary">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is javafile contains the servlet

```
package com.gaurav;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.Out;
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Set response content type


    // Actual logic goes here.

    //String name=request.getParameter("name");
    //out.println(name);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String user="system";
    String pass="inception";


    try{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        int salary=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("salary"));
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        String query="INSERT INTO employee VALUES(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stm=con.prepareStatement(query);
        stm.setInt(1, id);
        stm.setString(2, name);
        stm.setInt(3, salary);
        stm.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        out.println("class not found ");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        out.println("SQL Exception");
    }



}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // resource release
    super.destroy();
}
}
```

[file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wW9u.png)

whenever i tries to run the above program,it doesn't shows any error but when i write some data and press the submit button it thorws a ClassNotFound Exception.I don't have any idea whats happening.so someone help me.

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.gaurav.HelloServlet.doPost(HelloServlet.java:50)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Oracle 10g. From Oracle 9i onwards, support for `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is deprecated (documentation [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/111070-readme-083278.html)). Could you try using `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you loaded the correct oracle jar driver on your project.